# Is Oauth1.0 supported in Mule runtime 4.2?

Tags: mulesoft

The Mule4 HTTP connector only supports OAuth 2.0 (when using Anypoint Studio).
We need to call Third-Party APIs (from Mule flow) that requires OAuth 1.0 (HMAC-SHA1 signature method). Is there an available connector that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

The Mule 4 HTTP connector supports only the following [OAuth 2 methods](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-authentication):

- OAuth2 - Authorization Code
- OAuth2 - Client Credentials

An alternative could be to disable the built-in authentication methods and implement the [HMAC-SHA1 signing](https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html) yourself in the flow. Mule 4.2.x provides a  [DataWeave HMACWith() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-crypto-functions-hmacwith) that could be used to generate the signature.

Comment: Thanks aled, could you please share me the git link for the implementation ? As  i am new to mule 4?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try to implement it myself. You can try to follow the steps for the signing from the first link I shared. I'm not certain it is fully possible with the HTTP connector.

Comment: Is it possible in mule3.if yes ..could you please share the git link for oauth1.0 in mule3?